Flutter app universal links not working on iOS but works on Android
I have flutter app and deeplinks works fine when I click on button from gmail for Android app but not for iOS.

the URL in the email templates comes from courier, courier generates the cta URLs itself and then it is added to a button in a template via <a href https://718d95b0-XXXX-test.ct0.app>
Here is what I have so far:
apple-app-site-association
   {
      "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
          {
            "appID": "TeamId.BundleId",
            "paths": ["*", "/"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

Info.plist
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>DomainName</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
    <true/>

in iOS AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import courier_flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: CourierFlutterDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }


    override func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      open url: URL,
      options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
      // Handle the incoming URL and pass it to the Flutter engine
      if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "BundleId/deeplink", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        channel.invokeMethod("onDeepLinkReceived", arguments: url.absoluteString)
      }
      return true
    }
}

in flutter routes.dart
     GoRoute(
        name: NamedRoute.home,
        path: '/',
        redirect: (context, state) => state.locationWithQuery(
          '/dashboard',
        ),
      ),

Runner.entitlements
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:domain</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


have you added domain in associated domains? reference: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links?tab=xcode-ui#add-associated-domains

yes, all set, I will add the code to the question

Apple’s content delivery network requests the apple-app-site-association file for your domain within 24 hours.

the issue is not in Apple, the URL generated by courier for CTA is different than the one I added as a domain in Info.plist
